# Session data is lost if the web server is accessed by the machine name

Tags: asp.net, session, dns

I am facing a very strange issue. if I access my asp.net application with machine name then the application is not able to store/retrieve the values from the session.

I have an asp.net application in which I store few variables in the session on one page and I access them on the second page.

When I access my server with machine name(http://ultp_384/lem) I don't get any data from the session on the second page. but if I access it with localhost (http://localhost/lem) or IP address the application works fine and I am able to retrieve session data on the second page.

I have tried changing the Session mode from state to inproc but it does not help. It can be observed for other asp.net applications as well. so I am guessing that its not an issue of the application as such.

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what is happening in my case. Just in case if someone faces the same issue it might save their time.

have underscore in my server name(ultp_384). There is know issue with IE and cookies in this case.

Refer following link: [http://forums.iis.net/t/1150171.aspx?Cookie+problem+in+IIS7+and+IE+New+session+id+with+every+request](http://forums.iis.net/t/1150171.aspx?Cookie%20problem%20in%20IIS7%20and%20IE%20New%20session%20id%20with%20every%20request)

To summarize, if web server has underscore then the IE generates new session id with every request and hence the session data is lost as server creates new session for every request.

If you face similar issue, try accessing your site with different browsers like Firefox and chrome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the fully qualified domain name (eg, http://ultp_384.yourcompany.com/lem) for the first page request.

If that works, the problem is getting the session id cookie from the browser -- the first page request is in one domain, and the next page is in a different domain. The second page thus doesn't have access to the session id cookie associated with the session, so you lose the session information.

This link http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#intro has some information about the domain and path of cookies.